# Non-Duplication of Tags in SQL Insertion (Toxi)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Part of my form for user accounts asks people for their interests($tags) which are stored in MySQL with each $tag separated with a comma.

Each $tag is given an id and then a separate table links the users unique id with the $tag id.

This all works great - absolutely ideal BUT I would like to not duplicate tags thousands of times. For example, a lot of people will type 'gym' as an interest. It seems a waste to keep adding a new 'gym' $tag with a unique id, whereas once its been entered as a $tag once, that $tag id can then be associated with any new user id who happens to also type in 'gym'. Does that make sense?

My current code is below ($tags coming from a sanitised $_POST), and is inseretd into two tables:

1.tag_id which has a tag field for the $tag, each generating a unique id
2.tag_relation which matches the user id to the generated tag id.

```
$tags = strtoupper($tags);$tags= preg_split('/\,/', $tags);
foreach ($tags as $ind) 

{
$sql = "INSERT INTO tag_id (tag) VALUES('$ind')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}

foreach ($tags as $ids) 
{
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tag_id WHERE tag = '$ids'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$idinfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$id=$idinfo['t_id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tag_relation (user_id, tag_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$id')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

So my question is, can the above be modified to not duplicate $tags in the tag_id table, but match existing $tags from that table with the user id in tag_relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to create a `UNIQUE` index on the `tag`  column. You can then use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) to insert the new tag but suppress the duplicate key warning if it is already present in the table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tag_unique ON tag_id (tag);
```

When inserting the tag:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tag_id (tag) VALUES ('$ind');
```

Of course, before you do so, you will need to purge your existing table of duplicate tag values.  However, you cannot make use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` when using `INSERT IGNORE` if the value already exists. So to reliably get the `tag_id` you will need to continue querying for it as you are currently doing.

By the way - we assume the tag values in `$tags` have already been escaped against SQL injection if they originate from user input. If not, be sure to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on them in the loops. And consider migrating to a newer API than the `mysql_*()` functions such as MySQLi or PDO, which support parameterized queries.

Comment: Michael - works almost perfectly, thank you :) I can't mark it answered for another five minutes but I will. Thanks again

Comment: In addition to Michael's answer i suggest you to use INSERT IGNORE INTO tag_relation (user_id, tag_id) SELECT '$userId', t_id FROM tag_id WHERE tag = '$ind'

Comment: Michael, $tags has been sanitized. Vadim, i'll have a look at that. Thanks both :)